# Is there a way to invoke customized ErrorHandler for earlyRecordInterceptor in spring-kafka 2.8

Tags: spring-kafka

In spring-kafka 2.5.x, 2.6.x (non transactional case), if I add a customized  `RecordInterceptor` , this `RecordInterceptor`  will be invoked by method  `doInvokeRecodListener(record, iterator)` (because there is no `earlyRecordInterceptor`), inside the method, it `invokedErrorHandler` which can let me execute some customized errorhanler, spring-kafka 2.6.x source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2.6.x/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L1968). (I list the key source code from spring-kafka below)

```html
private RuntimeException doInvokeRecordListener(final ConsumerRecord<K, V> record,
  Iterator<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> iterator) {
  Object sample = startMicrometerSample();
  try {
      invokeOnMessage(record);
      successTimer(sample);
      recordInterceptAfter(record, null);
    }
  catch (RuntimeException e) {
    ...
    recordInterceptAfter(record, e);
    if (this.errorHandler == null) {
      throw e;
    }
    try {
    invokeErrorHandler(record, iterator, e); // here can invoke my customized Errorhandler
    ....
    return null;
}
```

But in spring-kafka 2.8, spring-kafka set the  `interceptBeforTx`  to `true` (according to [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.x/reference/html/#message-listener-container)), then the invoke process of my cusomInterceptor will be put in to `earlyRecordInterceptor` . But unfortunately, the process of `earlyRecordInterceptor`  **do not invoke any ErrorHandler**, then I cannot invoke my customize Errorhandler, spring-kafka2.8.x source code see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2.8.x/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L2432).

```html
private ConsumerRecord<K, V> checkEarlyIntercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> nextArg) {
  ConsumerRecord<K, V> next = nextArg;
  if (this.earlyRecordInterceptor != null) {
    next = this.earlyRecordInterceptor.intercept(next, this.consumer);
    if (next == null) {
      this.logger.debug(() -> "RecordInterceptor returned null, skipping: "
        + ListenerUtils.recordToString(nextArg));
    }
  }
  return next;
}
```

My question is why spring-kafka not invoke errorhandle for `earlyRecordInterceptor` ? If this can be enhanced? (Maybe also invoke errorhandler inside the process of `earlyRecordInterceptor`  method like doInvokeRecordListener did?)

Is there a way to invoke errorhandler for `earlyRecordInterceptor`?

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 0):

The `earlyRecordInterceptor` is only used the call the "before" method (`intercept`).

It is simply a reference to the same interceptor as `commonRecordInterceptor` which is called from `recordInterceptAfter`.

The early interceptor is never called when transactions are not used, but to revert to the previous behavior for transactions, set `interceptBeforTx` to false.

```java
private final RecordInterceptor<K, V> earlyRecordInterceptor =
        isInterceptBeforeTx() || this.kafkaTxManager == null
                ? getRecordInterceptor()
                : null;

private final RecordInterceptor<K, V> commonRecordInterceptor = getRecordInterceptor();
```

Comment: Also see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2082

Comment: Thank for your reply Gary. I noticed, the condition here is `isInterceptBeforeTx() || this.kafkaTxManager == null`, in our non-transactional case, seems this.kafkaTxManager is always null, then the earlyRecordInterceptor will be called.

Comment: In spring-kafka 2.5.x, 2.6.x, the condition for earlyRecordInterceptor is 
`earlyRecordInterceptor = isInterceptBeforeTx() ? getRecordInterceptor(): null;`
and default value for `interceptBeforTx` is `false` , then earlyRecordInterceptor is always null. Our customized recordInterceptor will invoked during the execution of `commonRecordInterceptor` (which invoked errorHandler)

Comment: Did that means, in non-transactional case, before spring-kafka2.8, our cusomized recordInterceptor is invoked by commonRecordInterceptor process. Since spring-kafka2.8, they will be invoked by earlyRecordInterceptor?

Comment: Both variables point to the same interceptor, so it is irrelevant. The `early...` and `record...` are only called for the "before" (`intercept`) method; they exist so that, when transactions are enabled, the user can decide whether the "before" method is called before or after the transaction starts. When transactions are NOT enabled, the "before" method is now called earlier than it used to be, but for more situations, that makes no difference.